# Erro ao colocar outros parâmetros na função Shell()

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando usar a função `Shell()` do `Vba` no `office 2010`, porém está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Erro de compilação
>
> Erra Esperado:=

Meu código está assim:

```
Dim programa As String: programa = "caminho do programa"

'Somente assim funciona
Shell(programa)

'Setando o parâmetro windowstyle ocorre o erro acima.
Shell(programa, vbNormalFocus)
```

Tava olhando na [documentação](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63) e mesmo assim continua dando erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema esta no facto de chamar a função `Shell` com os parêntesis e sem atribuir o valor da função a uma variável. Pode resolver o problema tirando os parêntesis:

```
Shell programa, vbNormalFocus
```

Ou atribuindo o valor da função a uma variável (e neste caso necessita dos parêntesis):

```
chamada = Shell(programa, vbNormalFocus)
```