# Como fazer uma rotina pública para todos formulários sem estar atrelada a um form?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, variáveis

Tenho vários formulários em minha aplicação, e posso iniciar a chamada por alguns deles em execução parcial para testes (não necessariamente INICIAR pelo formulário principal).

Além das variáveis públicas que ficam em um módulo, tentei fazer o mesmo com rotinas e funções públicas, para que não ficassem espalhadas em códigos de diversos formulários ou concentradas em um só, pois em qualquer desses casos a chamada parcial da aplicação não carregaria todas as funções e rotinas que poderiam ser solicitadas.

Tem como fazer isso?

Por exemplo, quero uma rotina pública que coloque os valores "default" em variáveis públicas, mas sem ser em um código de formulário.

```
     Public Sub InicializaVariaveisPublicas()

     VersaoATual = "2.03.017"

     QuantidadeMaximaProjetos = 2

     QuantidadeMaximaItens = 10

     ArrastoMouse = False

     MaximoTentativas = 3

     ...

     ...

     End Sub
```

**SOLUÇÂO**

Ver resposta abaixo

Comment: O que deu de errado quando colocou ela no módulo? É assim mesmo que faz.

Comment: Ocorre erro de sintaxe ao chamar a rotina, verifiquei nome, parâmetros, mas não encontrei nada. Vou tentar novamente

Comment: Uma dúvida, eu chamo uma das rotinas públicas como sendo o primeiro comando de um Form, ou seja, no Form_Activate. Pode ser esse o erro?

Comment: Coloca na resposta como ela fica dentro do módulo, com a assinatura do módulo toda e como você está chamando a função, testa chamar a função em um click e não no active também

Comment: Ricardo, o erro foi que eu estava chamando a rotina com parênteses para colocar dois argumentos, Rotina(a,b), bastou tirá-los e funcionou, mesmo sendo a primeira chamado do activate. Rotina a,b  Vou colocar na questão. Grato

Comment: No VB subs vc chama sem () e functions com ()

Comment: Ok, foi distração, pois antes tinha feito como função e alterei depois para rotina sem ter testado. Valeu!

Comment: Cria uma resposta para sua pergunta, nesses casos vc mesmo responde e aceita a resposta. Abs

Comment: @Leo veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68429/erro-ao-colocar-outros-par%C3%A2metros-na-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-shell/68442#68442) uma curta explicação do funcionamento dos parentesis.

Comment: Ok, foi isso mesmo que ocorreu... valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ERRO ENCONTRADO**

O erro foi por distração, eu estava chamando a rotina com parênteses para colocar dois argumentos: **Rotina(a, b)**, bastou tirá-los e funcionou, mesmo sendo a primeira chamada do Form_Activate, **Rotina a, b**.

Portanto, *basta fazer as rotinas e funções públicas em um único "módulo" que funciona*.

No meu caso tenho três módulos, um para as variáveis públicas, um para as rotinas e funções públicas e um para as macros do Excel.